# findmnt, mountinfo show non-existent partitions

Tags: mount, partition, block-device, lsblk

I noticed `findmnt -n -o SOURCE --target MOUNT_POINT` was returning lines containing block devices that didn't exist on my system:

```
TARGET                              SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/home/USER/mnt/070C6A0EB3DFA834 /dev/sdb1 vfat   rw,relatime,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
/home/USER/mnt/070C6A0EB3DFA834 /dev/sdc1 vfat   rw,relatime,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
```

I also noticed `cat /proc/self/mountinfo` shows similar results:

```
223 21 8:17 / /home/USER/mnt/MNT rw,relatime shared:206 - vfat /dev/sdb1 rw,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
263 223 8:33 / /home/USER/mnt/MNT rw,relatime shared:216 - vfat /dev/sdc1 rw,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
█
```

Both outputs indicate the same partition is named `/dev/sdb1` as well as `/dev/sdc1`. But the `/dev/sdb1` pathname doesn't exist on my system:

```
[my-hostname][0]$ findmnt -n -o SOURCE --target /home/USER/.usb-drive-symlink | xargs -L1 ls -l
ls: cannot access '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 33 Sep  3 19:40 /dev/sdc1
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the device was mounted, then removed from the system without un-mounting it first, and then later added to the system and re-mounted. Try `dmesg | grep sdb1` and `dmesg | grep sdc1`